# Scraping data from dynamically updating command line application

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to get some data from the program intel_gpu_top, it updates it's output dynamically much like top or nethogs.

```
 intel_gpu_top | grep render
```

displays the appropriate lines, but the lines are still updating in place. Also from that i can't send the lines anywhere else. Something like:

```
 intel_gpu_top | grep render >> output_lines.txt
```

does not work. Sometimes a fragment of a line will end up in the file.

if this was a command that wrote to the console normally i would just do something like

```
  intel_gpu_top | grep render | awk ...
```

And i would like to be able to replicate this functionality.

Also i don't think my problem is specific to intel_gpu_top, whatever solution there is, i would think, should also work for similar programs like top and nethogs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also I would like to be able to do this in python as well. But i can work with bash only.

Comment: I don't know the specific package, but it is probably relying on a library that manipulates stdout/stderr to provide the dynamic output such as the `curses` library. What is being written and what is being cleared at any one time is probably ambiguous from a redirect standpoint.

Comment: Write output to a file (`intel_gpu_top > file`) and upload it somewhere for a more detailed analysis.

Comment: And **check the program options**. `top` has "Starts top in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file." Maybe you have something similar...

Comment: @Cyrus, what is with the flurry of modifications of all questions by the established users in the past couple of days. Did somebody issue a bounty? I've seen hundreds of additional edits in the past 24 hours that normally wouldn't take place. Leffler probably had 100+ last night?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Sorry, I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an Intel GPU graphics card to try it out, but from the man pages:

```
   Options
       -s [samples per second]
              number of samples to acquire per second

       -o [output file]
              collect usage statistics to [file]. If file  is  "-",  run  non-
              interactively and output statistics to stdout.
```

So maybe try with `-o`?

Comment: in fact use `-o -` to then further pick the output from `stdout` using redirection and parse as usual... :)